How to use custom string for the 'App Interaction' and 'unknown' fields which show up in the wallet transaction history

One potential solution I came across is creating and uploading a program on the Solana blockchain using anchor, but so far, I’ve only been able to show custom messages in the program log. And I find it a bit overwhelming since I'm not using Rust.
Any guidance or resources you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

I am not sure I follow, but if you are looking for a way to get parsed transactions, Helius' enhanced API's would be a great place to start.
Using the transactions API you can get Human readable output,
Helius' enhanced API docs
Types of transactions supported ref: https://docs.helius.dev/resources/transaction-types

No, I want to modify how the fields show up inside the wallet's transaction history. As you can see in the image on the left, when I bought an NFT from Tensor, the transaction is clearly labeled, making it easy to identify by its title. However, on the right side, it just shows "App interaction," which is a transaction made through my app. How can I add my app's name, similar to how Tensor does it, and customize the "App Interaction" label to something more meaningful?

That depends on how the wallets are parsing their txs. If they are unaware of your app and what the tx is doing, a generic "wallet interaction" or something similar will show up. Only the Devs for that app and RPC operators like Helius can help you enrich the txs

Thank you, i will reach out to them.
